# The centralizer and normalizer of products of (SU(n) $\times$ SU(p) $\times$ …) in U(m)

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}
$Consider the [special unitary group $\SU(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group) and the [unitary group $\U(m)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group).

Below I specify a *specfic* way to embed $\frac{\SU(3)\times\SU(2)\times \SU(2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_6} \subset \U(16)$:

1. First we can embed the spin group $\Spin(10)\subset \U(16)$. Here we choose the $\mathbf{16}$-dimensional spinor representation of $\Spin(10)$ to be also the $\mathbf{16}$-dimensional fundamental representation of $\U(16)$. Thus, the data for the representation:
   $\text{$\mathbf{16}$ in $\Spin(10)$ as $\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$}$
   gives us an action of $\Spin(10)$ and $\U(16)$ on the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^{16}$.
2. Then, we can embed $\frac{\SU(3)\times\SU(2)\times \SU(2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_6}$ into $\Spin(10)$. See [the discussion of this embedding
   of $\SU(n)$ into $\Spin(2n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318145/is-sun-subset-textspin2n). Here we choose:

- the complex fundamental representation ${\mathbf 3}$ of SU(3),
- the complex fundamental representation ${\mathbf 2}$ of (any of) SU(2).
- the 1-dimensional representation (some number $k$) of $\U(1)$.

For example, we would denote the representation of ${\SU(3)\times\SU(2)\times \SU(2)\times \U(1)}$ as:
$
({\mathbf 3}, {\mathbf 2}, {\mathbf 1}, k)
$ or $
({\mathbf 3}, {\mathbf 1}, {\mathbf 2}, k)
$, or others.

$$\text{$({\mathbf 3}, {\mathbf 2}, {\mathbf 1}, 1) \oplus ({\mathbf 1}, {\mathbf 2}, {\mathbf 1}, -3)  \oplus  ({\mathbf 3}, {\mathbf 1}, {\mathbf 2}, -1) \oplus  ({\mathbf 1}, {\mathbf 1}, {\mathbf 2}, 3)$ in $\frac{\SU(3)\times\SU(2)\times \SU(2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_6}$ as a decomposition of $\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$}.$$
The data for this above representation gives us an action of $\frac{\SU(3)\times\SU(2)\times \SU(2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_6}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{16}$, which further gives its embedding  into $\U(16)$.

### Question

Then my question is about the [*centralizer* and *normalizer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer)  of this $\frac{\SU(3)\times\SU(2)\times \SU(2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_6}$ inside $\U(16)$? Which certainly depends on the embedding that I provided above. So what are the [*centralizer* and *normalizer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) inside $\U(16)$? My suspicion is that other than some U(1) factors, there could be additional discrete finite groups.